# Yammer API: return topics of a particular group

Tags: yammer

I am using embedded Yammer feed to get the feeds from a particular group.

Using embedded Yammer I want to retrieve all topics of that particular group.

Answer (score 1):

The API (embedded or REST) doesn't surface which topics are frequently used in a particular group. The closest thing in the API is [Search](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/searchjson), which allows you to search a group for topic names.